# My Lambda python Function is returning null even after successful execution

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Am a beginner to AWS services and python, i used below code in lambda to connect 
RDS and invoke this in API gateway
After Successful execution of below code it is returning null.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

import logging

import pymysql

import json

rds_host="host"

name="name"

password="password"

db_name="DB"

port = 3306

def save_events(event):

     """

       This function fetches content from mysql RDS instance

      """

    result = []

    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, 

    db=db_name,connect_timeout=30)

    with conn.cursor() as cur:

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM exercise WHERE bid = '1'")

    for row in cur:

       result.append(list(row))

       print ("Data from RDS...")

       print (result)

    cur.close()

     print(json.dumps({'bodyParts':result}))


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    save_events(event)
```

Comment: I don't see any `return` statements in your functions.  A function without any `return` statement will return `None` by default.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment by @John Gordon, you need to `return` something from your `lambda_handler` function.

It should be something like:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    save_events(event)
    return {
       "statusCode": 200,
       "result": "Here is my result"
    }
```

Additionally, I don't see any `return` statement from `save_events` either.